# Debian Remmina to xrdp server: Port open on server, filtered at client?

Tags: networking, debian, remote-desktop, remmina, xrdp

I'm having a weird issue with remmina remote desktop / xrdp

I've not been able to connect from my desktop machine to a machine in the next room for a couple of days. I've been moving things around network/IT wise and I'm not sure exactly what has caused this.

My desktop connects to a router via a switch. The machine I am trying to RDP to is connected via the same switch.

When I do an nmap port scan from my desktop, I get a response telling me that port 3389 is filtered from the target machine.

```
nmap -sT 192.168.2.112 -p 3389
```

Port 22 is open however.

What is really weird is that on the server itself, `nmap -sT 127.0.0.1 -p 3389` states that the port is open.

I'm not 100 % sure if this indicates anything useful?

I've looked at the xrdp log files inside `/var/log` on the server, and checked the `~/.xsession-errors` file as well. I don't see anything that indicates any issue in any of these 3 files.

The only thing I notice is a message from `systemctl` - something about not being able to open a PID file. However service is still marked as started/green dot/ok. (I can't view the log message as other things have been printed in the log since I saw it.)

Nothing obvious in `journalctl -xe`.

Had a look at my pfSense box for anything obvious which might be filtering traffic somehow. Not sure if it should be relevant since traffic should go via the switch not the router, since the 3 systems (server, desktop, router) connect via the same switch.

Any thoughts? I might just try uninstalling and re-installing xrdp?

Edit: Restarting the service I get this log:

Can't open PID file `/run/xrdp/xrdp.pid` (yet?) after start: no such file or directory
Started xrdp daemon
starting xrdp with pid 2340
listening on port 3389 on 0.0.0.0

Any of that useful? Looks like it started ok?

Comment: All of this seems to indicate regular old firewall rules on the server. Have you checked those?

Comment: @user1686 I can take a look but I don't have any reason to expect they have changed over the last few days. I'll get back to you in a moment

Comment: @user1686 Strange: You were indeed correct for some reason the filewall config no longer permitted port 3389. After re-enabling it, nmap says the port it open. However, still no luck connecting. "Lost connection to the RDP server" - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this was a security/certificates issue. I booted from another external boot disk with Debian installed and it worked fine. I created a new configuration in Remmina before connecting. This probably reset the credentials / certificates or whatever is used for security.

The ip address of the server changed, so this may have had something to do with why it stopped connecting correctly, despite changing the IP within the Remmina config.

Essentially: Delete your saved connection config and re-produce it.